# How to define multiple environment variables from a single sh script output

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to execute a tool in a sh block that sets multiple environment variables. Then I need to export those environment variables out the sh step, into a withEnv step to be available to another step.

I know I could accomplish something like this by executing the tool and ansible within the same sh block. If possible I would like to leverage the ansiblePlaybook plugin to accomplish this task.

```
stage('Example') {
    steps {
        // Run the tool that generates the eval block
        sh 'some-tool'
        // Generates output like:
        // TOKENA='foo'; TOKENB='bar'; export TOKENA; export TOKENB; echo "success"

        // This is where I need help. 
        // How to translate the script output from above into variables
        // So that I can make them available to the ansiblePlaybook step.
        withEnv([TOKENA=TOKENA, TOKENB=TOKENB]) {
            ansiblePlaybook( 
                // ... irrelevant details
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The code I provided is incomplete. I don't expect any results from it.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for `withCredentials`.

Answer (score 7):

I have recently had the same problem, needed to save several environment variables using the Jenkins' `withEnv` block. That is what worked for me:

```
    stage('Do some hard work'){
        steps {
            withEnv(["MY_VAR_1=${VALUE_1}", "MY_VAR_2=${VALUE_2}"]) {
                script {
                    bat (
                            script: 'echo "Doing some Hard work with ${MY_VAR_1} and ${MY_VAR_2}"'
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

everything you have is shell. including output from `some-tool`.

so why not to put this `some-tool` inside `ansible`?

however, if you could make `some-tool` output as only token assignment then following code will work

```
def env = new ConfigSlurper().parse(" TOKENA='foo'; TOKENB='bar'; ")
```